# how to debug watch connectivity

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, watchconnectivity

I am attempting to start an HKWorkoutSession on the Apple Watch and send the heart rate data near-instantaneously to the iPhone for near real-time display. To accomplish this, I'm using WatchConnectivity's `sendMessage` method. I do not need replies from the phone/watch, so I'm using the version of sendMessage that doesn't use a reply handler.

The heart rate data isn't making it to the phone, and I'm struggling to understand why. I'm not getting any sorts of error messages that are helpful. How do I find out what is going wrong? I have attached both the phone app and the watch app to the debugger, but since the message never gets to the phone, I'm having a ton of trouble figuring out what's going on because obviously my breakpoints in the phone code aren't being reached. Earlier, I was using the replyHandler version of `sendMessage`, which has a closure for error handling. Using that, I was able to see that my errors were (sometimes) due a timeout in receiving a return message. The `didReceiveMessage` delegate on the phone was never reached, though, so I'm not surprised that it never sent its return message. I assume there's something wrong with the connection between the phone app and watch app, but I've checked the `isReachable` boolean, as well as `isPaired` and `isWatchAppInstalled`.

So I guess I'm wondering if you have any tips about debugging techniques for Watch Connectivity. And, if you want to take a look at my code too, here it is. Let me know if you see anything glaringly wrong about it. (Sorry it's a tad sloppy--just trying to get things to work right now.)

ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WCSessionDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var bpmLabel: UILabel!    
let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
var bpmArray = [Double]()
var wcSession: WCSession?

// WC Session Delegate methods
func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
    if let error = error {
        print("WC Session activation failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }
}

func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) {
    print("WC has become inactive")
}

func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) {
    print("WC was deactivated")
}

func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) {
    guard let bpm = message["bpm"] as? Double else { return }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.bpmArray.append(bpm)
        self.bpmLabel.text = String(bpm)
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if WCSession.isSupported() {
        wcSession = WCSession.default
        wcSession?.delegate = self
        wcSession?.activate()
    }

    if !(wcSession?.isPaired)! || !(wcSession?.isWatchAppInstalled)! {
        print("PAIRING PROBLEM")
    }
}
```

InterfaceController:

```
var wcSession: WCSession?
@IBOutlet var bpm: WKInterfaceLabel!
let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
var workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession?

func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
    if let error = error {
        print("WC Session activation failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }
}

func workoutSession(_ workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession, didChangeTo toState: HKWorkoutSessionState, from fromState: HKWorkoutSessionState, date: Date) {
    print("here")
}

func workoutSession(_ workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("Workout session failure")
}

override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    super.awake(withContext: context)
    workoutSession?.delegate = self
    guard let wcSess = self.wcSession else { return }
    wcSess.activate()
}

// modified from https://github.com/coolioxlr/watchOS-2-heartrate/blob/master/VimoHeartRate%20WatchKit%20App%20Extension/InterfaceController.swift
func createHeartRateStreamingQuery() -> HKQuery? {

    if !HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
        print("health data not available")
    }

    guard let quantityType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRate) else { return nil }

    let heartRateQuery = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: quantityType, predicate: nil, anchor: nil, limit: Int(HKObjectQueryNoLimit)) { (query, sampleObjects, deletedObjects, newAnchor, error) -> Void in
        self.updateHeartRate(samples: sampleObjects)
    }

    heartRateQuery.updateHandler = {(query, samples, deleteObjects, newAnchor, error) -> Void in
        self.updateHeartRate(samples: samples)
    }
    return heartRateQuery
}

// modified from https://github.com/coolioxlr/watchOS-2-heartrate/blob/master/VimoHeartRate%20WatchKit%20App%20Extension/InterfaceController.swift
func updateHeartRate(samples: [HKSample]?) {

    guard let heartRateSamples = samples as? [HKQuantitySample] else { return }
    guard let sample = heartRateSamples.first else { return }
    let value = sample.quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit(from: "count/min"))

    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        self.bpm.setText(String(UInt16(value)))
    }

    let dataToSendToPhone = ["bpm":String(value)]


    if (wcSession?.isReachable)! {
        self.wcSession?.sendMessage(dataToSendToPhone, replyHandler: nil)
    }
    else {
        print("WC Session not reachable")
    }
}

override func willActivate() {
    super.willActivate()
    if WCSession.isSupported() {
        wcSession = WCSession.default
        wcSession?.delegate = self
        wcSession?.activate()
    }
}

override func didDeactivate() {
    super.didDeactivate()
}    

@IBAction func recordIsTapped() {

    let workoutConfiguration = HKWorkoutConfiguration()
    workoutConfiguration.activityType = .other
    workoutConfiguration.locationType = .unknown

    // Inspired by https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SpeedySloth/Introduction/Intro.html
    do {
        try self.workoutSession = HKWorkoutSession(configuration: workoutConfiguration)
        healthStore.start(self.workoutSession!)
        if HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
            if let query = createHeartRateStreamingQuery() {
                self.healthStore.execute(query)
            }
        }
        else {
            print("Healthkit unavailable")
        }
    }
    catch {
        fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

Comment: I haven't fully reviewed your code, but have you watched/read the transcripts for WatchConnectivity portions of the online Apple Developer Conference videos?  They may help you get a general idea of WatchConnectivity behavior.  There is also some sample code referenced.

Comment: I haven't watched them, but I have done quite a bit of reading of Apple's documentation, and I've read many online tutorials. Perhaps the videos will offer something new, though.